# Problems creating an image gallery using dojo

Tags: dojo

I am having problems creating an image gallery using dojo. The images form the json file do not render. I am not sure what the problem is. 
This is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dojox.image.Gallery");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
dojo.require("dojo.parser");
djConfig.useCommentedJson=true;
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){  
var itemNameMap = {imageThumbAttr: "thumb",imageLargeAttr: "large"};
var request = {query: {}, count: 20};
dijit.byId('gallery1').setDataStore(itemStore,request, itemNameMap);
});
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<div id="gallery1" dojoType="dojox.image.Gallery" style="background-color:gainsboro;">    
</div>
<div jsId="itemStore" dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore"  url="TotalEnrollmentMapData.json"> </div>
```

The json file is

```
var maps={identifier:'Enrollment Maps' ,
label:'Maps',
items:[

{  thumb:"maps_2.0/2012 Enrollment.png",
large:"maps_2.0/2012 Enrollment.png",
title:"I'm wide,me"
},
                                                  ,
{  thumb:"maps_2.0/2012 Enrollment Change.png",
large:"maps_2.0/2012 Enrollment Change.png",
title:"I'm a horizontal picture"},

{  thumb:"maps_2.0/2012 FTIAC Enrollment.png",
large:"maps_2.0/2012 FTIAC Enrollment.png",
title:"I'm another horizontal picture"},

{  thumb:"maps_2.0/2012 FTIAC Enrollment Change.png",
large:"maps_2.0/2012 FTIAC Enrollment Change.png",
title:"I'm a vertical picture"}
]};
```

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using? According to https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/index.html, the dojox.image.Gallery is abandoned, so it may be prudent not to use dojox.image.Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a fairly large dojo application based around image galleries, and after experimenting with dojox/image/Gallery, I decided that it was prudent to write my own widget from scratch.

That being said, your code seems to be derived from this

http://dojocampus.org/explorer/#Dojox_Image_Gallery_Default

and if you look at the JSON file that the gallery is pulling data from, it is an actual JSON file (not JavaScript, which is what you are saying is in your file).

As a first step, I would try to fetch some items from your store directly to confirm that it's working as you would expect, and only then investigate whether the contents of said store conforms to what the dojox/image/Gallery is expecting to see.